# Entropy and Probabilities: does not "particle indistinguishability" alter probability values?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

This issue has been bothering me for a bit but I fail to find a convincing answer.
It all has to do with particles indistinguishability and how they alter the concept of probability.

As I understood it, in the microcanonical ensemble all configurations are equiprobable: we find the macroscopic equilibrium configuration by selecting the one which occurs with higher probability.

But indistinguishability must somehow alter what we compute as probabilities.
Let me clarify directly with an example.

I have a system consisting of three boxes, and three particles. Each particle has to go in one box. There is no energy, only configurational entropy.

All it matters to me, macroscopic observer, is how many boxes are left empty, $1$, $2$ or $3$.

An observed unable to distiguish particles could get one of the following configurations:
$$ (3, 0, 0) \\
(0,3,0) \\
(0,0,3) \\
(1,1,1) \\
(1,2,0) \\
(2,1,0) \\
(0,1,2) \\
(0,2,1) \\
(1,0,2) \\
(2,0,1) $$

Now I wonder, what is the probability (in the mathematical sense) of having a configuration whereby one box is empty?

Looking at the above, one might be tempted to fallaciously reply such probability equals $ \frac{6}{10} $.

An easy calculation shows the probability of having one empty box equals $ \frac{6}{9}$.

Indeed, treating particles as indistinguishable does not delete the fact that the configuration say $(1,2,0)$ can occur in $3$ different ways, and so on. Hence, the six configurations above with one empty box can occur in $18$ ways: adding the $(3,0,0)$ which can occur in $3$ ways, and the $(1,1,1)$, which can occur in $6$ ways, one gets $27$ total possibilities, not $10$ as one would if considered indistibguishability.

If I wanted to find the most probable configuration in the microcanonical ensemble, I would need to look at probabilities.  How does indistinguishability fit in all this?
I studied Gibbs’ paradox, and I see how indistinguishability solves it: but is not the microcanonical intuitive picture somehow altered??

Yes for an observer maybe $(A, BC, 0)$ is indistinguishable from $ (B, AC, 0)$, yet these occurences must count if we look at mathematical probabilities.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Your classical intuition is leading you astray. Quantum mechanics *truly does not care* which way you reorder your particles so for indistinguishable particles so $(1,2,0)$ really is only a single state. This means that while is you were doing your experiment with particles obeying [Bose-Einstein statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics) the probability of having one box empty would really be $\frac{6}{10}$

Comment: That is very interesting, thanks,  but I never mentioned quantum mechanics. Does the question not make sense in a classical world? For sure Boltzmann or Gibbs must have faced (and resolved) such issue in a fully classical sense, well before quantum mechanics.

Comment: Gibbs and Boltzmann did not know about quantum mechanics, but they did work out that particles have to obey the statistics of indistinguishable particles, which from a modern viewpoint is much more natural to view in the context of quantum mechanics than classically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indistinguishability is more subtle than that. As a simple example, consider two particles ($A$ and $B$) and two states. If the particles are distinguishable, there are four equally probable configurations,
$$(A, B), (B, A), (AB, 0), (0, AB)$$
so, e.g. the probability of having both states occupied is $1/2$. If you had another observer that couldn't distinguish between the particles (suppose they're red and green, and the observer is colorblind), the probabilities remain exactly the same, even though the particles are now "indistinguishable". The microcanonical ensemble doesn't depend on the observer.

True indistinguishability is deeper: it means that the separate labels $A$ and $B$ are completely meaningless, so that the states could be, e.g.
$$(1, 1), (2, 0), (0, 2)$$
if the particles are bosons, so that the probability of having both states be occupied is now $1/3$. This is sometimes expressed by saying that bosons have a tendency to 'clump up'.

You can try putting labels on -- for instance, maybe we can think of $A$ as the "first particle we put in" and $B$ as the second. Then formally the states $(A, B)$ and $(B, A)$ are
$$a_0^\dagger a_1^\dagger |0 \rangle, \quad a_1^\dagger a_0^\dagger |0 \rangle$$
but these are the *exact same state* because $a_0^\dagger$ and $a_1^\dagger$ commute, so you are double counting the state. It's the same mistake as saying that when you flip a coin, you can get heads, not-tails, and tails, so the chance of getting tails must be $1/3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am truly reassured by your statement about the microcanonical ensemble  being observer-independent. Let me ponder about the matter a bit. It seems that, as @By Simmetry was maybe hinting at, the fact that Gibbs  noted that the definition of entropy works only if we include indistinguishability was an ante litteram evidence of the need for QM.

Comment: @Smerdjakov It's a neat puzzle! Note that the microcanonical ensemble is observer-independent, but thermodynamics is _not_, as explained by [this](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/jaynes.pdf) neat paper by Jaynes. Basically, if you work thermodynamically ($N \gg 1$ particles) it's completely self-consistent for the colorblind observer to treat the particles as indistinguishable, and a non-colorblind observer to treat the very same particles as distinguishable. At a thermodynamic level it doesn't matter if indistinguishability is 'true', quantum mechanical indistinguishability.

Comment: This is how Gibbs and company figured out the $1/N!$ indistinguishability factor without quantum mechanics -- for the purposes of thermodynamics the quantum-ness didn't really matter.